# How do I reassign which file was renamed to which in git?

Tags: git, rename

I see

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    foo.java -> foo_setup.java
        new file:   foo_details.java
```

But actually most of `foo.java` is in `foo_details.java`, so I'd rather it be

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    foo.java -> foo_details.java
        new file:   foo_setup.java
```

Is there a difference? If so, how can I reassign what file `foo.java` was "actually" renamed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `diff.renamelimit` configuration value to increase or decrease the amount of files that git uses to detect renames.

However, this is usually completely unnecessary when *committing*. The reason is that git does in no way *record* renames. The rename detection is a feature of the commands that *show* the status, log, or commit content, but the actual commit itself does not store this information, at all.

So you don't actually have to do anything, if you succeed in getting git to change the status to better (in your opinion) reflect what you renamed to what, the actual commit will be identical to what you could commit right now.